# Number of lines containing a substring in a DataFrame

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I tried this solution to test if a string in substring:

```
val reg = ".*\\[CS_RES\\].*".r
reg.findAllIn(my_DataFrame).length
```

But it is not working because I can't apply `findAllIn` to a Dataframe.

I tried this second solution, I converted my `DataFrame` to `RDD`:

```
val rows: RDD[Row] = myDataFrame.rdd

val processedRDD = rows.map{

    str => 
         val patternReg = ".*\\[CS_RES\\].*".r
         val result = patternReg.findAllIn(str).length
         (str, result)
}
```

it displays an error:

```
<console>:69: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Row
 required: CharSequence
       val result = patternReg.findAllIn(str).length
```

How can I apply a Regex on a DataFrame scala in the first solution to compute the `number of the lines` that contain the string `[CS_RES]`
or if someone have a solution for the second solution ?

Comment: what's the schema for your dataframe?

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`regexp_extract`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) function to filter and count the lines. For example:

```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

  private val session: SparkSession = ...

  import session.implicits._

  val myDataFrame = Seq(
    (1L, "abc"),
    (2L, "def"),
    (3L, "a[CS_RES]b"),
    (4L, "adg")
  ).toDF("id", "text")

  val resultRegex = myDataFrame.where(regexp_extract($"text", "\\[CS_RES\\]", 0).notEqual("")).count()

  println(resultRegex) // outputs 1
```

The idea is: if the first group (i=0) returned by `regexp_extract` is not an empty string, the substring is found. The invocation of `count()` returns the total number of those strings.

But if you need to find *only exact matches* of substrings, the solution can be simplified by using `locate` function:

```
  val resultLocate = myDataFrame.where(locate("[CS_RES]", $"text") > 0).count()

  println(resultLocate) // outputs 1
```

Comment: I changed it like this:
  val myDataFrame = Seq(Origin_Datatframe).toDF("summary")

  val resultRegex = myDataFrame.where(regexp_extract($"summary", "\\[CS_RES\\]", 0).notEqual("")).count()
  
   error: value where is not a member of Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column]

Comment: it work on your exemple but myDataframe contain 1 million of line

Comment: It is not necessary to wrap the original dataframe into `Seq`. Have you tried `Origin_Datatframe.where(...)` or `input_jiraissue.where(...)`?

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
val reg = ".*\\[CS_RES\\].*".r
val contains=udf((s:String)=>reg.findAllIn(s).length >0)

val cnt = df.select($"summary").filter(contains($"summary")).count()
```

Comment: 18/06/28 12:59:20 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 6.0 in stage 21.0 (TID 146, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (string) => boolean)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I changed: (s:String)

Comment: That's what I get for typing on StackOverflow instead of the repl :)